# What happened to the Steins;Gate 0 anime?

Tags: steins-gate

I was waiting for another episode since the Okabe in *Steins;Gate 0* wasn't shown to reunite with Kurisu.

Did *Steins;Gate 0* really end? Are there any OVAs of this?

Comment: i haven't seen the anime but it was originally a Visual Novel so no idea which route or ending it's chosen to adapt

Comment: Yes an OVA of steins gate 0 is supposed to be aired on November 28th. since steins gate 0 is supposed to be an alternate time line I think okabe won't meet kurisu( mear speculation). so I suggest you to watch steins gate episode 23 if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did *Steins;Gate 0* really end?

Yes. The episode list ends with episode 23, which was broadcasted earliest on Sep 27, 2018.

> The Okabe in *Steins;Gate 0* wasn't shown to reunite with Kurisu.

[Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/STEINS;GATE_(%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1)#%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81) stated that since the game's premise is replaying multiple times with multiple endings, there are some scenes from the game which are cut, and some anime original scenes added. However, this might not be the reason why that scene was cut (i.e. speculation at best).

> Are there any OVAs of this?

[Volume 6 of the Blu-ray set](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BA%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88-%E3%82%BC%E3%83%AD-Vol-6-Blu-ray-%E5%AE%AE%E9%87%8E%E7%9C%9F%E5%AE%88/dp/B07BGM2MHX) (which according to Amazon will be released on Dec 21, 2018, but possibly earlier somewhere else) contains 1 bonus unaired episode.

> 【収録内容】
>   第21話~第23話+未放送1話

However, it's too early to know what is the content (there's no detail on that).

Comment: Note: I haven't watched/played this spinoff. Also, wake me up when there's new info on the bonus episode... or feel free to write an answer with better information :)

Comment: The true end of game ends the same way the Anime does, but without the Okabe saving Suzu+Mayuri scene. There's also plenty of room for another season or more content as there's still a lot of unanswered questions. For starters, there's still 11 years before the young Suzu goes back in time (presumably, she's the last piece of the puzzle as you still need the Suzu who's aware of Operation Skuld).

Answer (score 2):

Steins; Gate 0 ended just like how Calvin and Hobbes did, at it's prime.

If they probably made another episode, reuniting the two, many fans might or might not like it, which makes it simpler to have a semi-cliffhanger.

Hope this answers your question